# Deploy manager - cyclic reference when updating InstanceTemplate with network references

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a simple Cloud Deploy configuration to deploy network, InstanceTemplate and InstanceGroupManager (see below).

Deployment has been created successfully.

Then, I tried to replace InstanceTemplate resource with a new version by renaming InstanceTemplate resource.

During the update, Google Deploy Manager complained about cyclic reference error. But, as far, as I can see, there is none.

How can I update InstanceTemplate resource without getting manager errors?

Below is the initial template and update error.

### Initial template

```yaml
resources:
  - name: t2-vpc-network
    type: gcp-types/compute-v1:networks
    properties:
      name: t2-vpc-network
      routingConfig:
        routingMode: REGIONAL
      autoCreateSubnetworks: false

  - name: t2-vpc-subnetwork-europe-west1
    type: gcp-types/compute-v1:subnetworks
    properties:
      name: t2-vpc-subnetwork
      network: $(ref.t2-vpc-network.selfLink)
      region: europe-west1
      ipCidrRange: 10.10.10.0/24
  - name: t2-esp-hc
    type: gcp-types/compute-v1:healthChecks
    properties:
      type: HTTP
      checkIntervalSec: 10
      timeoutSec: 5
      unhealthyThreshold: 3
      healthyThreshold: 2
      httpHealthCheck:
        port: 8080
        requestPath: /endpoints_status
  - type: gcp-types/compute-v1:instanceTemplates
    name: t2-esp-instance-template-europe-west1-1
    properties:
      properties:
        machineType: f1-micro
        disks:
          - deviceName: boot
            boot: true
            type: PERSISTENT
            autoDelete: true
            mode: READ_WRITE
            initializeParams:
              sourceImage: projects/gce-uefi-images/global/images/cos-stable-80-12739-91-0
        networkInterfaces:
          - network: $(ref.t2-vpc-network.selfLink)
            subnetwork: $(ref.t2-vpc-subnetwork-europe-west1.selfLink)

  - type: gcp-types/compute-v1:regionAutoscalers
    name: t2-esp-group-autoscaler-europe-west1
    properties:
      region: europe-west1
      target: $(ref.t2-esp-group-europe-west1.selfLink)
      autoscalingPolicy:
        coolDownPeriodSec: 120
        cpuUtilization:
          utilizationTarget: 0.8
        minNumReplicas: 1
        maxNumReplicas: 5

  - type: gcp-types/compute-v1:regionInstanceGroupManagers
    name: t2-esp-group-europe-west1
    properties:
      region: europe-west1
      targetSize: 1
      baseInstanceName: t2-esp-instance
      instanceTemplate: $(ref.t2-esp-instance-template-europe-west1-1.selfLink)
      updatePolicy:
        minimalAction: 'REPLACE'
        type: 'PROACTIVE'
      namedPorts:
        - name: http
          port: 80
        - name: https
          port: 443
      autoHealingPolicies:
        - healthCheck: $(ref.t2-esp-hc.selfLink)
          initialDelaySec: 120
          actionType: RECREATE
```

### Changed template

Instance template has a different name (to delete old template and create new one). This is the only change here.

```yaml
resources:
  - name: t2-vpc-network
    type: gcp-types/compute-v1:networks
    properties:
      name: t2-vpc-network
      routingConfig:
        routingMode: REGIONAL
      autoCreateSubnetworks: false

  - name: t2-vpc-subnetwork-europe-west1
    type: gcp-types/compute-v1:subnetworks
    properties:
      name: t2-vpc-subnetwork
      network: $(ref.t2-vpc-network.selfLink)
      region: europe-west1
      ipCidrRange: 10.10.10.0/24
  - name: t2-esp-hc
    type: gcp-types/compute-v1:healthChecks
    properties:
      type: HTTP
      checkIntervalSec: 10
      timeoutSec: 5
      unhealthyThreshold: 3
      healthyThreshold: 2
      httpHealthCheck:
        port: 8080
        requestPath: /endpoints_status
  - type: gcp-types/compute-v1:instanceTemplates
    name: t2-esp-instance-template-europe-west1-2
    properties:
      properties:
        machineType: f1-micro
        disks:
          - deviceName: boot
            boot: true
            type: PERSISTENT
            autoDelete: true
            mode: READ_WRITE
            initializeParams:
              sourceImage: projects/gce-uefi-images/global/images/cos-stable-80-12739-91-0
        networkInterfaces:
          - network: $(ref.t2-vpc-network.selfLink)
            subnetwork: $(ref.t2-vpc-subnetwork-europe-west1.selfLink)

  - type: gcp-types/compute-v1:regionAutoscalers
    name: t2-esp-group-autoscaler-europe-west1
    properties:
      region: europe-west1
      target: $(ref.t2-esp-group-europe-west1.selfLink)
      autoscalingPolicy:
        coolDownPeriodSec: 120
        cpuUtilization:
          utilizationTarget: 0.8
        minNumReplicas: 1
        maxNumReplicas: 5

  - type: gcp-types/compute-v1:regionInstanceGroupManagers
    name: t2-esp-group-europe-west1
    properties:
      region: europe-west1
      targetSize: 1
      baseInstanceName: t2-esp-instance
      instanceTemplate: $(ref.t2-esp-instance-template-europe-west1-2.selfLink)
      updatePolicy:
        minimalAction: 'REPLACE'
        type: 'PROACTIVE'
      namedPorts:
        - name: http
          port: 80
        - name: https
          port: 443
      autoHealingPolicies:
        - healthCheck: $(ref.t2-esp-hc.selfLink)
          initialDelaySec: 120
          actionType: RECREATE
```

### Error

```
code: CYCLIC_REFERENCES
  message: |
    A cycle was found during reference analysis:
    Detected cycle:
    t2-vpc-subnetwork-europe-west1 <- t2-esp-instance-template-europe-west1-1 <- t2-esp-group-europe-west1 <- t2-esp-instance-template-europe-west1-2
```

Comment: When updating a template, deployment manager only looks at the
[changes of the configurations within the template](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployments/updating-deployments#make_changes_to_your_configuration), not the name of
the template.

Comment: @dany L How how exactly does it help? I have an impression, that you mistook deployment template (yaml) with instance template. I think, I should have written InstanceTemplate. This is one of the cloud resource types.

Comment: When you say you "tried to replace InstanceTemplate resource with a new version by renaming InstanceTemplate resource.", did you simply change the version and redeployed? Or was it accordingly with what this documentation [1] suggests when updating Deployment? [1] https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployments/updating-deployments#prepare_your_update

Comment: I have tried one-step deploy (just version change). It is completely feasible on, for example, AWS. Also multi step deploy is not desired for CI/CD scenarions and automated deployments.

As I understand, this is the only option for Google, right? If so, maybe you have some suggestions how to incorporate this approach with automated deployments. If you add this as an answer, I will probably accept it.

Comment: I added an answer. Let me know if you already use a version control system.

Comment: Yes, I do, of course. Please, just add to the begining of your answer that my case can only be accomplished with two stage update (as you did in your comment), so the answer will be more profitable for other users.

Comment: Just updated my answer.  And from my understanding, your deployment config files above were not intially in the VCS?

Comment: To be exact, they were, as everything I do. They were also much more complex, than the example I presented here. But they were not run as a part of automated pipeline yet, as their main purpose was to test the deployment flow beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using CI/CD automation environment, storing the deployment configuration file in a version control system is a first step. You can then perform the update, as per this Google [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/updating-a-deployment#open_the_updated_template).

For version update such as you did, in [CI/CD automated environments](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/best-practices#continuous_integration_ci_continuous_deployment_cd), you will need to use a version control system such as Git (most popular), Subversion, and Mercurial. A version control system, among many [benefits](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/devops/devops-tech-version-control) will allow you to:

- Fall back to a previous known good configuration,
- Provide an audit trail for changes,
- Use the configuration as part of a continuous deployment system,

Version control provides a logical means to organize files and coordinate their creation, controlled access, ***updating***, and deletion across teams and organizations.

Automation and continuous integration rely on these files for the source code of the automation itself, as well as the configuration to be automated and the data to be distributed.

When you make a change to the configuration files, the VCS will inform of what changed and where the change was as well as show the incompatibility of versions, among other things.

This is another [example](https://medium.com/pankaj-khuranas-blog/automate-infrastructure-as-code-with-gcp-deployment-manager-747bfc07d839) of using Deployment Manager in an automation environment using Git as a VCS. This [link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) shows how to install Git.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is dependency loops (code: CYCLIC_REFERENCES). It [Indicates that your configuration has a dependency loop](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/troubleshooting#dependency_loops_code_cyclic_references). For example, if resource A depends on resource B, B depends on C, and C depends on A.

You can see that the loop in your Deploy configuration is this:
t2-vpc-subnetwork-europe-west1 <- t2-esp-instance-template-europe-west1-1 <- t2-esp-group-europe-west1 <- t2-esp-instance-template-europe-west1-2

To resolve the error, change the references so that the loop is broken.

Comment: Please, read the whole question. I know, that DM shows dependency cycle. But I don't SEE any actual dependency cycle. Especially for a subnetwork, which depends only on network (which, in turn, depends on nothing)